# SQL thinks 100 is less than 56

Tags: sql

I'm sorting a list in Sequel Pro and it's not sorting right. Here's the query:

```
Select personID, yearID, x, y
from Table
Where x>=25
order by y asc
```

And here's what I'm getting:

```
playerID    yearID  x    y

****    1930    40  170
****    1921    59  171
****    1930    41  174
****    1938    50  175
****    1927    47  175
****    1937    40  183
****    1931    46  184
****    1930    56  191
****    2002    27  56
****    1973    26  56
****    2008    25  56
```

The table extends in both directions - it starts at the top with y=100 and ends at the bottom with y=99. Obviously it thinks that 3-digit numbers are lower than 2-digit numbers. But why? How can I fix this?

Also, y is type VARCHAR with length 255.

Comment: Because varchar types aren't treated as numbers, can the data type be set to numeric instead?

Comment: Select personID, yearID, x, y
from Table
Where x>=25
order by DECIMAL(y) asc

Comment: It does that in order to annoy you so much that you finally give up and fix your design by using the **correct** data type for numbers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your sarcasm and complete unhelpfulness. To respond to your comments - I am new to relational databases and I'm just asking for help. Also, I mentioned that I was using Sequel Pro (this was part of the original question, I did not add it after I saw your comment). Next time you might want to actually read the question.

Comment: @user3081195: Just FYI, as far as I know Sequel Pro is just a management application for MySQL databases. The database you're using is MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

What you are experiencing is known as *lexicographical sorting*. This means that, because your field is a `varchar` instead of a numeric type like `int`, the server doesn't know you're actually dealing with numbers. Instead of sorting by numeric value (which you want), it's performing normal alphabetical sorting. `1` comes before `5`, so it gets sorted first.

The real solution to your problem is to use the right data types for your fields. If your data is numeric, use an appropriate numeric type (i.e. `int` for integer values, `float` or `double` for floating-point values, `decimal` for decimal values, etc.). If you do this, sorting will work as you expect.

The alternative is to perform a conversion in the `order by` clause to force sorting by numbers.

```
Select personID, yearID, x, y
from Table
Where x>=25
order by convert(int, y) asc
```

But you should *really* fix the fields; this solution is just a band-aid.

Comment: I tried this but got this :                                           An error occurred when trying to change the field 'y' via

ALTER TABLE `Table` CHANGE `y` `y` INT(255)
 NULL
 DEFAULT NULL

MySQL said: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'y' at row 7

Comment: Row 7 contains no value. It is not null.

Comment: @user3081195: What does that value mean, then? What would you do with a value that is not numeric?

Comment: I didn't create the file, I imported it from somewhere.

Comment: @user3081195: That still doesn't say what you would expect to happen when the value is an empty string or other non-numeric value.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to convert the value of Y to a number before sorting.  Something like this:

```
Select personID, yearID, x, y
from Table
Where x>=25
order by cast(y as int) asc
```

Expect problems if not everything in Y can be converted to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

As the `y` field is text, it's correct that the value `56` should come after the value `191`. That is how text is sorted.

If you want to sort on the numeric value that the texts represent, you have to convert each value to a number when you sort them:

```
Select personID, yearID, x, y
from Table
Where x>=25
order by cast(y as signed integer) asc
```

Answer (score 0):

`CAST` the `VARCHAR` as `Numeric`, It will work:-

```
Select personID, yearID, x, y
from Table
Where x>=25
order by CAST(y AS Numeric(10,0)) asc
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT fields,CONVERT(y,UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS ynum
FROM table
ORDER BY ynum;